# Sub-tags and over-tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

In group theory there is a global tag, group-theory. There are also a number of sub-tags, such as finite-groups, abelian-groups, topological-groups, geometric-group-theory, etc. I am sure there are similar sub-tags for other subjects.

Would it not be a good idea to put something on these tags to "persuade" question askers to also use the group-theory tag (or at least the abstract-algebra tag, although this is a bit general, but maybe that's just my opinion)? It seems a number of questions which are straight out of an introductory course do not tag group-theory, but virtually identical ones do.

**EDIT**: As suggested in the comments, I have done this to (most of*) the group-theory related tags. However, it would be nice if this was done uniformly across the board...

*I didn't touch the [(group-cohomology)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-cohomology) tag as it needs a tag in the first place and I do not really know enough about it to write one! It would be useful if someone more knowledgeable about this than me wrote it...

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from editing the tag wiki to include these nudges... :)

Comment: Sure, but then I wouldn't want someone to change them all back again!

Comment: A related feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2781) It is marked ([meta-tag:status-declined]).

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is necessarily a good idea.

1. Considering that only 5 tags are allowed per question, asking users to observe hierarchies may not be worth our while. For example: would you ask a user who tagged `lie-groups` to also include `topological-groups`, `smooth-manifolds`, `group-theory`, and `differential-topology` *just* because the "hierarchy" calls for it?
2. And why isolate `group-theory`? If you are going to ask users to consider using "parent tags", all inheritances should be observed. Why isn't `general-topology` a parent tag for `topological-groups` when `group-theory` is?
3. In fact, we have [previously established tag wikis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galois-theory) which calls for **exactly the opposite** of what you are proposing.
4. Note that there are character limits to tag wiki excerpts, **and line breaks are not observed**. Is this request (for users to use both the parent and child tags) really important enough to be placed in the limited space?
5. And if we were to add such a request, I think we should have something beyond just "Consider using..." A few more words would be better. Something like "For questions focusing on the group theoretical aspects of topological-groups, consider using also the [group-theory] tag" would be much more informative and avoid points 1 and 2 above.

Comment: For point two, I isolated group theory because it is the subject I know most about. I should have made that more clear in the question - the question was meant to be about the general senario, but using the example of group theory.

Comment: For point 1 basically my point is that tags which are used by people sitting a first course in group theory, such as (finite-groups) or (abelian-groups), which do not require someone with an in-depth knowledge of the subject really should be accompanied by the (group-theory) tag (perhaps other people use SE differently, but I tend to just go to my favourite tag and nowhere else, and so I miss these questions). Lie groups is a subject unto itself, and anyone using such a tag can probably work it all out for themselves. Perhaps they should be asked to "consider using any other appropriate tags"?

Comment: For point four, the excerpt is meant to be just that: an excerpt. You only need one line, maybe two - if you are using a tag you just need to know that you have the correct tag, you do not need to read an in-depth discussion or a complete definition. That is what the wiki proper is for.

Comment: I agree with your point five, but only for the more "advanced" tags, and not (finite-groups) etc.

Comment: (...and I haven't said anything about point three because I would rather have a discussion than cite precedent...unless that precedent was discussed before?)

Comment: Roger on your first comment. About second comment: you explicitly mentioned "topological groups" and "geometric group theory" in the OP; neither of those are encountered by people sitting a first course in group theory. If you limit to only extremely specific cases like "finite groups" or "abelian groups", I agree with your third comment. [That is to say, I agree with your fourth comment. But I don't think such requests belong _at all_ on the more "advanced tags".]

Comment: (About my second comment) Oh, I am sorry! I seem to have no read over my question before replying to your post! What I said in my response to your point one is my proper opinion; what I said in the question should be edited to reflect this!

Comment: I do not understand the second half of your comment: "If you limit to only extremely specific cases like "finite groups" or "abelian groups", I agree with your third comment. [That is to say, I agree with your fourth comment. But I don't think such requests belong at all on the more "advanced tags".]" Third comment? Fourth comment?......

Comment: A propos my point three, the edit history to the galois-theory and field-theory tags indicated that I was the one responsible for creating the tag wikis. (I had thought otherwise though....`:-p`). There may have been a discussion held before I was even actively participating in the site ([see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/471/should-this-be-tagged-galois-theory)), though in the early days we were not always so clear about documenting everything on Meta. Sometimes things are just hashed on in comments of the relevant questions.

Comment: @user1729: when I wrote [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/sub-tags-and-over-tags/6613#comment23548_6613) your fourth comment hadn't appeared. After I hit the enter key I noticed that the second half of my comment is essentially what your wrote in your fourth comment. So I added a parenthetical to express that fact. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Can I try and clarify your opinion? (I do not know what that it a question - I suppose I am asking you if you want to reply to what follows...): You agree with me on the basic tags - that they should be accompanied by their over-tag. However, you feel that the more advanced tags can stand on their own and encouraging people to use other tags waste space in the excerpt. This wasting of space is important here because the more advanced tags need a more in-depth excerpt.

Comment: Almost: it is not just that it wastes space. Many of the more advanced tags lie at the intersection of many fields, and it is not even clear which tags (if any) should be considered its "over/super/parent tag". Moreover, one needs to consider how a tag is used. If I were looking for a question on finite-groups, I will consider searching both (finite-groups) and (group-theory). But if I were looking for a question about geometric group theory, I will _never_ expect to find anything useful under (group-theory).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6473/discussion-between-willie-wong-and-user1729)

Comment: Unfortunately, chat does not work on my computer. Now, you say that if you were looking for a question about geometric group theory then you will never expect to find anything useful under (group-theory). This may be the case, but it should not be, because questions about geometric group theory are answering questions about groups! If you look at the questions with this tag then the vast majority of them should be tagged (group-theory) too. (If you are doing research in group theory you are, broadly speaking, either doing rep. theory or geometric group theory, or studying top. groups...)

Comment: Ah, chat doesn't work for you. But can you [read the transcripts](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6473)? If not I'll copy and paste what I wrote afterward here. I think that will address your previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, I just cannot log in. I think I understand your point (w.r.t. advanced tags), and I agree with it in general - that subjects usually have very fuzzy boundaries. However, I do think that some indication of taggins should be included, even if it is just to say "consider using some other tags". Because although the asker might know a lot about their subject, they might not know anything about SE!

Comment: Two more points and I will stop. (a) Compare with biological taxonomy. There's a reason why we usually list only the genus + species. If the tags are too inclusive they become useless as means of classification. (b) There is already an automatic function that draws intertag relations. If you go to [a tag's page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-cohomology), on the right hand side "related tags" are shown ordered by their frequency (of joint appearance). I disagree that for the "advanced" tags any other indication is necessary.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point about the related tags. Sure, one can see related tags, but that doesn't imply a user will decide to add them. However, they should be encouraged to tag - tagging is good!!!

Comment: "tagging is good" until you dilute a tag so that it becomes useless. We are only allowed five tags per question. Tagging $X$ and $Y$ denotes $X\wedge Y$ (or $X\vee Y$, depending on how you choose to read it). But if $X\prec Y$ then $X\wedge Y$ give no more information then $X$ by itself. And if $X \not\prec Y$ one shouldn't always encourage $Y$ to be used in conjunction with $X$. I would much rather see (group-theory) remain a tag that is useful for those taking a first course in group theory, instead of a hodgepodge of everything "group".

Answer (score 0):

I would like another solution:
make some kind of tag hierarchy 
but if somebody wants to see all post with a particular tag, it also gets to see the question of all related sub-tags,

In the example above  if a question is tagged lie-group it also shows up when I check on [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory), and other more general tags.

Comment: +1: It's a cool idea, but -1 because that's not really the way tags typically work (elsewhere too, not just StackExchange), and it would be confusing to get used to.  So, net +/- 0.